# Saving a loop's output in a vector in R

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I have a .cvs file which consists of 4 columns and 120 rows.
I'm attempting to go through every row and where ever i see a "1" in the third column (which here is called "Dam") , i want to save that row in a matrix called "Dam.one"

Here's my code so far:

```
DamType = c( "Dam.one", "Dam.two", "Dam.three", "NoDam.one", "NoDam.two", "NoDam.three")

for (i in 1:120) {
    if (mercury.raw[i,]["Dam"] == 1) {
        if (mercury.raw[i,]["Type"] == 1){
            DamType["Dam.one"] <-  mercury.raw[i,]  
}}}
```

This is the first 6 entries of the data set:`

```
> mercury.raw
                    Lake Mercury Dam Type
1                ALLEN.P   1.080   1    1
2            ALLIGATOR.P   0.025   1    1
3        A.SAGUNTICOOK.L   0.570   0    2
4      BALCH&STUMP.PONDS   0.770   0    2
5           BASKAHEGAN.L   0.790   1    2
6          BAUNEAG.BEG.L   0.750   0    2
```

I want `DamType["Dam.one"]`to be equal to:

```
                 Lake Mercury Dam Type
1                ALLEN.P   1.080   1    1
2            ALLIGATOR.P   0.025   1    1
```

I don't know what is wrong with it.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't know either. Could you explain the error you get? Maybe also show us what `mercury.raw` is? See [mcve].

Comment: @manotheshark what? He's got no variable called `Dam.one`, and `"Dam" == 1` is always going to evaluate to `FALSE`.

Comment: @dash2 I mistyped `DamType` instead of `mercury.raw`.  From his question he is searching the third column ("Dam") for whenever he see a `1`.  I'm assuming there are times he doesn't have a one and really just wants to subset his data.

Comment: DamType is a vector of characters, what should `DamType["Dam.one"]` be?

Comment: I've added more info. I hope that makes my question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

A matrix cannot be stored in a vector.  A list can store multiple matrices (or data frames in this case).  This looks like you are trying to subset your data and a `for` loop is not required.

```
DamType <- list()
DamType[["Dam.one"]] <- mercury.raw[mercury.raw$Dam == 1 & mercury.raw$Type == 1, ]

> DamType$Dam.one
         Lake Mercury Dam Type
1     ALLEN.P   1.080   1    1
2 ALLIGATOR.P   0.025   1    1
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest getting more familiar with R and common packages, such as dplyr.

```
library(dplyr)
dam_grouped <- mercury.raw %>% group_by(Dam)
```